# ERROR 01:09:18,071 | Unable to obtain a connection to the POP3 server

Tags: james

I try to install & configure Apache JAMES, and when I start run.bat in cmd in Windows I have this error

```
ERROR 01:19:18,142 | org.apache.james.fetchmail.StoreProcessor | A MessagingException has terminated processing of this Folder
javax.mail.MessagingException: Unable to obtain a connection to the POP3 server (java.net.UnknownHostException: pop.server.com)
        at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.store.pop3.connection.POP3Connection.getConnection(POP3Connection.java:154)
        at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.store.pop3.connection.POP3Connection.protocolConnect(POP3Connection.java:121)
        at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.store.pop3.connection.POP3ConnectionPool.createPoolConnection(POP3ConnectionPool.java:155)
        at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.store.pop3.connection.POP3ConnectionPool.protocolConnect(POP3ConnectionPool.java:137)
        at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.store.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:164)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:248)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:91)
        at org.apache.james.fetchmail.StoreProcessor.process(StoreProcessor.java:63)
        at org.apache.james.fetchmail.FetchMail.run(FetchMail.java:487)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: pop.server.com
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.util.MailConnection.getConnectedSocket(MailConnection.java:310)
        at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.util.MailConnection.getConnection(MailConnection.java:253)
        at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.store.pop3.connection.POP3Connection.getConnection(POP3Connection.java:152)
        ... 15 more
```

Can you help me please

Answer (score 1):

The pop host server `pop.server.com` seems not exist.

Check your configurations and settings to fix it.